# Kendo UI with backbonejs

Tags: backbone.js, javascript-framework, kendo-ui

Do you think is possible to use backbone js with Kendo widgets for the UI? or Kendo framework is too strong for integration?

PS: i'm not a expert of anyone of the two

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've recently published a sample project showing how to integrate a Kendo grid with BackboneJS: https://github.com/kendo-labs/kendo-backbone

Comment: Man, i can't thank you quite enough. i even asked this question 2days ago and you also posted it on kendo forum.

Comment: i would just like to ask. about this on your code. "kendo.backboneModel and kendo.backboneCollection" What does this do really?

Comment: Check the kendo.backbone.js file which defines those methods. It is a short one I promise :)

Comment: Hi, I would like to ask if how can i use this if i'm using backbone,require and kendo??

Comment: @AtanasKorchev I'm getting a 404 error when trying to go navigate to your url.

Answer (score 7):

I've not used Kendo, but I don't imagine this would be an issue. I use jQuery.UI and other web UI toolkits with Backbone just fine.

Comment: i just liked the simplicity and the comprehensiveness of kendo. I don't like patching several libraries

Comment: +1. i've looked through the kendo website some more and i really like what i'm seeing! going to give them a try next time i need something

Answer (score 0):

On one of the projects i've worked on, we integrated both together without an issue. Backbone is not a very obstrusive framework anyway.

Answer (score -2):

May be, you might consider also Sencha, dhtmlx and jQuery UI.